# Phone Shuts Down, Apps Force Close Since New SD Card

Tags: external-sd, crashes, force-close

I've got a Sony Ericcson Xperia Play that comes with an 8GB microSD card, which is definitely not enough for me as I like to put a lot of music on my phone (streaming is very poor on my network). So I bought a **Sandisk 32GB MicroSDHC Class 4 Memory Card** which is a MicroSD card like any other, right?

Ever since I put the card into my phone, my phone keeps shutting down and nearly all apps have a Force Close error. I've not installed any new apps since installing the new MicroSD and I've even uninstalled a bunch to see if it would help. **Why does my new MicroSD break my phone?**

If it helps, I'm running Android 2.3.3 stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting the SD card on the phone itself seemed to do the trick. My apps are finally running and my phone longer keeps shutting down with the new SDHC. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try switching back to the original SD card and see if the issues still continue. At the least, that would help you figure out whether or not the SD card is really the problem. Also, did you move any apps that had been moved to SD back to your phone before switching cards?

Comment: No, I couldn't move the apps to the phone before switching as I didn't have enough space. I simply put both SD cards into my computer and drag-and-dropped files from the old one to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

It happens on my Android 2.3.3. Every week, I backup of all my data. In my Class 10 MMC, it crashes the app backup folder and hides (or deletes) the .apk files.

I have solved the problem by not installing battery backup software or free antivirus.